# Angular/Firebase app ~10seconds until change shows in browser

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am running into a strange angular 4 refresh issue when using firebase authentication.

I was able to reproduce the issue in a simple app that should show if a user was able to login using firebase auth (Google account) or not.

The issue is, that the result message gets printed in the console, but it does not get displayed in the browser right away. After around 10 seconds the screen refreshes and the error message shows up.

How can I avoid this delay?

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  msg: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  login() {
    this.authService.loginWithGoogle()
      .then(() => {
          console.log('success');
          this.msg = 'success';
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
         console.log('error:'+ err);
         this.msg = err.message;
      });
  }
}
```

app.compontent.html

```
<div>Error is: {{msg}}</div>
<button (click)="login()">
Login
</button>
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
}

loginWithGoogle() {
     return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new 
firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
}
```

You can look at the issue here: https://jaidev1-27a1b.firebaseapp.com/

Use any google account for login.

**UPDATE:** This only happens with chrome. Using chrome 59

Answer (score 0):

It is because of cache. Disable cache while debugging.